# sending and receiving complex objects with ksoap to wcf

Tags: android, wcf

Hi i've been using ksoap for quite a while now,and all this time i was received arrays of complex objects.Now i need to send one I'm trying for a week but i can't manage it.My guess is that the complex object isn't mapped correctly on the server side.I've caught the message i'm sending with a packet sniffer.I think something's wrong with the namespaces and the mapping.Let me post you what i've done so far.The web service is wcf so I'll post you also the soap message from the wcftestclient,and also what i'm sending from my android application.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btn;
private Button btn1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) { 

            SoapObject soapObjectRequest = new SoapObject("http://microsoft.com/webservices/","InsertStudentAbsences");

            SRV_Students_Absence objStudentAbsences = new SRV_Students_Absence();

            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();             
            propertyInfo.setName("objStudentAbsences");
            propertyInfo.setType(SRV_Students_Absence.class);
            propertyInfo.setValue(objStudentAbsences);




            PropertyInfo propertyInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();                
            propertyInfo1.setName("connString");
            propertyInfo1.setType(String.class);
            propertyInfo1.setValue("server=verl,1524;Database=olDB;UID=sa;Password=7Esta#KAz");







            soapObjectRequest.addProperty(propertyInfo1);
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty(propertyInfo);
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty("Company","8");
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty("Lng","00");
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty("MainPeriod","80");
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty("UserID","14453");
            soapObjectRequest.addProperty("CourseDate","2012-11-06");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapSerializationEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;             


            soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObjectRequest);


            soapSerializationEnvelope.addMapping(soapObjectRequest.getNamespace(), "SRV_Students_Absence", objStudentAbsences.getClass());
            //soapSerializationEnvelope.addMapping(soapObjectRequest.getNamespace(), "SRV_Absence_Category", SRV_Absence_Category.class);
 //soapSerializationEnvelope.addMapping("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService_StudentGrades", "SRV_Student", SRV_Student.class);


            try {
                /**
                 * Mail the letter.
                 */
                HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE("http://androidwcf.schoolportal.gr");             
                httpTransportSE.call("http://microsoft.com/webservices/"+"IVertiSchool_SRV/InsertStudentAbsences", soapSerializationEnvelope);

                httpTransportSE.debug=true;



                SoapObject soapObjectResponse = (SoapObject)soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();





            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();


            }




        }
    });

}
```

and this is the class that implemetns KvmSerializable:

```
public class SRV_Students_Absence implements KvmSerializable {

private int AbCode;
private String AbNum;
private int AbsCatID;
private String ActID;
private String Cause;
private int  ClCode;
private int CoCode;
private String  CompanyCode;
private String CourseDate;
private boolean Flag;
private String InsDate;
private int InsWay;
private String IsParentsInf;
private String IsVerified;
private String LngCode;
private String MainPeriod;
private String SmsFlag;
private int StuCode;
private int TimeCode;
private String UserIdName;
private String WPCID;
private String WPGID;
private SRV_Student objAC;
private SRV_Absence_Category objStudent;


public SRV_Students_Absence(){

    AbCode= 0;
    AbNum= null;
    AbsCatID= 421;
    ActID= null;
    Cause= null;
    ClCode= 375;
    CoCode= 7628;
    CompanyCode= "8";
    CourseDate= "11/6/2012 9:50 AM";
    Flag=false;
    InsDate=null;
    InsWay=3;
    IsParentsInf=null;
    IsVerified=null;
    LngCode="00";
    MainPeriod=null;
    SmsFlag=null;
    StuCode=1359;
    TimeCode=1963;
    UserIdName=null;
    WPCID=null;
    WPGID=null;
    objAC=null;
    objStudent=null;

}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

    System.out.println("arxh");

      switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println(">0");
            return AbCode;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            return AbNum;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            return AbsCatID;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            return ActID;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
            return Cause;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("5");
            return ClCode;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("6");
            return CoCode;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("7");
            return CompanyCode;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("8");
            return CourseDate;
        case 9:
            System.out.println("9");
            return Flag;
        case 10:
            System.out.println("10");
            return InsDate;
        case 11:
            System.out.println("11");
            return InsWay;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("12");
            return IsParentsInf;
        case 13:
            System.out.println("13");
            return IsVerified;
        case 14:
            System.out.println("14");
            return LngCode;
        case 15:
            System.out.println("15");
            return MainPeriod;
        case 16:
            System.out.println("16");
            return SmsFlag;
        case 17:
            System.out.println("17");
            return StuCode;
        case 18:
            System.out.println("18");
            return TimeCode;
        case 19:
            System.out.println("19");
            return UserIdName;
        case 20:
            System.out.println("20");
            return WPCID;
        case 21:
            System.out.println("21");
            return WPGID;
        case 22:
            System.out.println("22");
            return objAC;
        case 23:
            System.out.println("23");
            return objStudent;
        default:break;
        }

      return 005;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 24;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {



      switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "AbCode";
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
             info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
             info.name = "AbNum";
             break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;             
            info.name = "AbsCatID";
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "ActID";
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Cause";
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "ClCode";
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "CoCode";
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "CompanyCode";
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "CourseDate";
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS;
            info.name = "Flag";
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "InsDate";
            break;
        case 11:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "InsWay";
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "IsParentsInf";
            break;
        case 13:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "IsVerified";
            break;
        case 14:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "LngCode";
            break;
        case 15:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "MainPeriod";
            break;
        case 16:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "SmsFlag";
            break;
        case 17:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "StuCode";
            break;
        case 18:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            info.name = "TimeCode";
            break;
        case 19:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "UserIdName";
            break;
        case 20:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "WPCID";
            break;
        case 21:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "WPGID";
            break;
        case 22:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = SRV_Absence_Category.class;
            info.name = "objAC";
            break;
        case 23:
            System.out.println(":D "+arg0);
            info.type = SRV_Student.class;
            info.name = "objStudent";
            break;
        default:break;
        }


}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object value) {

    System.out.println("setting Property");

      switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
             AbCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 1:
             AbNum  = value.toString();
        case 2:
            AbsCatID=(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
        case 3:
            ActID = value.toString();
        case 4:
            Cause = value.toString();
        case 5:
            ClCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 6:
            CoCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 7:
            CompanyCode= value.toString();
        case 8:
            CourseDate = value.toString();
        case 9:
            Flag = Boolean.getBoolean(value.toString());
        case 10:
            InsDate = value.toString();
        case 11:
            InsWay = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 12:
            IsParentsInf = value.toString();
        case 13:
            IsVerified = value.toString();
        case 14:
            LngCode = value.toString();
        case 15:
            MainPeriod = value.toString();
        case 16:
            SmsFlag = value.toString();
        case 17:
            StuCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 18:
            TimeCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        case 19:
            UserIdName = value.toString();
        case 20:
            WPCID = value.toString();
        case 21:
            WPGID= value.toString();
        case 22:
            objAC= null;
        case 23:
            objStudent= null;
        }


}

}
```

guys I'm really stack if you have any experience in this matter give me a direction.
Thank you for your time.